# "Хронический", но "хранить"

Tags: этимология

Интересно, тут получается плавающая гласная в корне. Или слова "хронический" и "хранить" происходят от разных корней?

Comment: Очень остроумный вопросик! Хронический насморк сохраняет сопли в носу)

Comment: Ну да)))) Они хронически хранятся в носу))))))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Хранить - славянский корень "хран". 
Хронический - от древнегреческого "chronos" - время.

Comment: У Шанского: общеславянское "хоронить" происходит от chorna - защита, охрана, которое, в свою очередь, происходит от слова, обозначающего еду, питье. Какая тут связь со временем?

Answer (score 2):

А еще слово ХРАНИТЬ родственно с ХОРОНИТЬ, которое развилось из праславянского ХОРНИТИ (прятать, хранить),в результате изменения у вост. славян -ОР-между согласными в полногласное сочетание -ОРО-, а также возникновения в слове значения "предавать земле" (умершего)